# WPF UI not updating (Callback function)

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
        public void SetDeviceConnect(double  x)
        {
            Testdevice = "aaa";
            Debug.WriteLine("aaa");            
        }
```

"SetDeviceConnect" is a Callback function, I can ensure that "Debug.WriteLine("aaa");" can be executed, and the value of "Testdevice" has also changed to "aaa", but the interface does not refresh to "aaa".

This is my xmal file.
MainWindow.xmal

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Testdevice}" Width="50" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"></TextBox>
```

The "Open" function is a button binding event. When I click the button, but the interface can be refreshed to "bbb", what's going on?

```
        private void Open()
        {
            Testdevice = "bbb";
        }
```

Comment: How do you call `SetDeviceConnect`? How is `MainWindowViewModel` implemented?